# How can I debug/step-through/watch my Node.js in Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, debugging

Sorry, maybe this belongs in programmers stack exchange, but I'm trying to get in to Node.js web development, and I really need to ability to step through my code in order to gain a deeper understanding of just what is happening in all the tutorials I'm using.

I've done some googling, but it looks like everything is written assuming you're in a *nix or OSX environment.

I've tried [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), but I'm being greeted with errors whenever I try to run process._debugProcess() with the PID.

Comment: What errors are you greeted with? It would be helpful if you provided them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JetBrains WebStorm is relatively inexpensive IDE you can use with Node.js, which is quite feature rich considering the price.

Watch the demonstration video and you should get an idea to see if it's the kind of thing which could be helpful.

http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Alternatively you could use Eclipse and get this up and running.

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be an option, as Ubuntu doesn't like my RAID controller.

Comment: More likely than not. Was just hoping for some more options.